# How can I format a var_dump's output for use as a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that spits out an array using `print_r` and would like to capture the information inside a variable to input it into a function for a specific use case. *I've simplified the output to make it easier to understand.*

```
[fruit] => 'banana'
[color] => 'yellow'
[sizes] => array('small', 'medium')
```

I would like it formatted as so:

```
$var = 'fruit' => 'banana', 'color' => 'yellow', 'sizes' => array('small', 'medium');
```

This way I can copy and paste the output of the first and assign it to a new default variable.

Comment: Consider using [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: I don;t understand why you are copy/pasting anything? Why not just pass the variable into the function?

Comment: Would [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) work?

Comment: @Mike - It's just for use as a default variable. I am, but I was just wondering if there was a quicker way than manually editing the array.

Comment: `var_export()` is what I was looking for. Thanks Rocket.

Comment: @neoian I think the suggestion by kojiro to serialize might make some sense in your case then. You can use JSON or PHP's native serialization. This makes an array/object into a string which can then be de-serialized back into array/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions for this:

1. `var_export()`

   - Pro: Outputs in a format that can be simply copy/pasted into a PHP script.
   - Con: Has to be pasted into the script. If you use `eval()` to read it in that's horrible practice and I will cut you.
2. `json_encode()/json_decode()`

   - Pro: Widely used across *many* languages, human-readable, easy to understand.
   - Con: Not natively supported in older versions of PHP
3. `serialize()/unserialize()`

   - Pro: Available in all versions of PHP
   - Con: Makes use of non-printing characters [like NULL bytes] that can cause problems with IO workflows that are not explicitly aware of this fact.

Comment: `var_export()` works perfectly fine for what I am doing. It's a list of states and their latitudes and longitudes. I'll end up putting them in the database if the need arises, but for now this works well.

Answer (score 1):

try using `var_export();` [var_export tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it with `<pre></pre>` tag, so it will look like that :

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($var);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: That gives the former, I am looking to print the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Might also consider print_r which operates similarly but provides a second argument that, when set to 'true', will return the value as a variable rather than printing it to STDOUT.